# SSRS Report Builder expression error with IIF( ) function

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Recently I've encountered an inconsistency with the use of IIF() function in SSRS. I am working on an aggregate function with multiple conditions. Suppose I have this code:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!MATL_STAT.Value="Disposed", Fields!MATL_SIZE.Value,0))
```

By description, the expression determines the sum of the sizes of the MATL with a `MATL_STAT = "Disposed"` but everytime I run the report there is an **#Error**.

My theory is that you can't put fields in the "true option" of IIF() function.

Now, if my theory is correct, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: IIRC this should work. Could you have a NULL (particularly a DbNull) in one of those fields throwing things off?

Comment: I already eliminated all the null values on my query using `NVL()` function. btw, I use Oracle.

Comment: You can most definitely put fields in the true option of the IIF function. Sometimes you get #error when it is expecting a different data type.  Can you do CStr(Fields!MATL_STAT.Value) = CStr("Disposed") and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Actually I solved it already using `CDbl()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extensive research using builtin function is SSRS reporting services, the field is summing different data types (double/int). To unify the data type, I use `CDbl()` function like this:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!MATL_STAT.Value="Disposed", CDbl(Fields!MATL_SIZE.Value),CDbl(0.0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Decimal conversion (CDEC) as well reason being the value output is an amount coming in decimals..